# Unable to set the delegate to class in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates

This is their example function

```
[GTMagBarDevice sharedDevice].delegate = self;
```

I tried rewriting it in swift like this

```
GTMagBarDevice.sharedDevice().delegate = self;
```

But I am receiving an error "type view controller does not conform to protocol GTMagBarDeviceDelegate"

Any ideas?

**Update**

I have implemented all the required functions, this is what it says in the .h file i am bridging

```
@protocol GTMagBarDeviceDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)magbarDevice:(GTMagBarDevice*)device accessoryConnected:(BOOL)state;
- (void)magbarDevice:(GTMagBarDevice*)device componentFailed:(int)components;
```

And this is the implantation

```
func magbarDevice(magbarDevice: GTMagBarDevice, accessoryConnected isAccessoryConnected: Bool) {

}

func magbarDevice(magbarDevice: GTMagBarDevice, componentFailed components: Int) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your function signatures are incorrect. Try these instead:

```
func magbarDevice(device: GTMagBarDevice!, accessoryConnected state: Bool) {

}
func magbarDevice(device: GTMagBarDevice!, componentFailed components: Int32) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the methods that the protocol you are conforming to requires.